# Есть(,) уходим с дороги!

Tags: пунктуация, жаргон, сложное-предложение

> — Есть(,) уходим с дороги! — Майкл рванул рычаги управления, выводя танк назад и вправо.

Ставится ли запятая? Слово *есть* в данном контексте означает *да*, *будет исполнено*, и я рискну предположить, что это отдельная грамматическая основа — а если быть точнее, подлежащее. Но это ведь профессиональный сленг, всякое может быть...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробую подвести **итог**:

1) Возможно, устав требует точного воспроизведения команды, однако в боевых условиях это **не всегда возможно**, там оперативность важнее формальной точности.

2) Изменение команды (Есть, уходим с дороги!) ещё **и более информативно,** так как это сообщение о том, что команда не только понята, но уже выполняется.

3) В художественной литературе автор изображает именно **реальную ситуацию**, и поэтому именно ее **надо обозначить с помощью знаков препинания.** Запятая для этого — наилучший вариант, так как пауза после *есть* присутствует, но это не такая длительная пауза, которая соответствует тире.

Поэтому **ставим запятую**.

Comment: Попробую подвести итог? Чему итог?

Comment: Своим размышлениям на эту тему с учетом полученной информации, только и всего, в  первом ответе не получилось это сделать. Кстати,  хотелось бы понять, какой письменный вариант предпочитаете Вы.

Comment: Объединение в одну фразу звука готовности исполнить  приказания(Есть!) и принятого решения (в вольном, не уставном варианте — не Уйти, и даже не Ухожу, а Уходим) не может обойтись без серьёзной паузы. Поэтому — не запятая. ======= По поводу двух ответов: мы видим их порознь, и уверенность, что они выстроятся в нужном порядке, безосновательна. Всякий ответ, исходя из этого, ответ — новый. Сейчас ответ выглядит, словно подведение итогов всему, что есть на странице.

Answer (score 1):

Современные воинские уставы требуют короткого ответа "Есть". Военнослужащий, получив приказ, отвечает: "Есть" - и затем выполняет его. Во времена Красной Армии от бойца требовали повторить приказание. *Выслушав приказание, отвечай "есть" и повтори полученное приказание. Например : "есть- позвать старшину". ([ПРАВИЛА ПОВЕДЕНИЯ КРАСНОАРМЕЙЦА НА СЛУЖБЕ И ВНЕ СЛУЖБЫ](http://www.antik1941.ru/new_catalog/?mode=descr&item_id=438)).

Приказания должны отдаваться в повелительном наклонении, и повторять их нужно было дословно.

— Уходить с дороги! 
— Есть уходить с дороги!

Современные словари дают такие фразы без знаков препинания после *есть*.

В вашем случае, скорее всего команда была отдана в нестандартном виде (*Уходим* вместо *уходить*) и ответ последовал в той же форме: "Есть(?) уходим". Ситуация нестандартная, скорее всего, правилами не предусмотренная. Как выход из положения, я бы использовал "красноармейскую" пунктуацию — тире, как в "ПРАВИЛАХ ПОВЕДЕНИЯ КРАСНОАРМЕЙЦА".

На мой взгляд, запятая после *есть* превращает его из военного термина в "гражданское" междометие для выражения эмоций. В крайнем случае нужно ставить восклицательный знак. Или тире, как писали во времена Красной Армии.

Comment: С восклицательным это будет правильно (и слов не изменит): первая часть — приказание усвоил, вторая — обращение к подчинённым или к самому себе.

Comment: А есть ещё литературные  примеры  (с запятой, тире или без знаков)  при "измененной" команде? И как там писали во времена Красной Армии?

Answer (score 0):

**Есть, уходим с дороги!**

Это междометие.

Из словаря: 3. ЕСТЬ, межд. Воен. Ответ подчинённого, обозначающий, что команда понята и принята к исполнению. Сняться с якоря! - Е. сняться с якоря!

Возможны **два варианта употребления**  междометия:

Вариант 1.  Есть уйти с дороги.  Принята команда уйти с дороги.

Вариант 2. Есть, уходим с дороги! Команда принята, уходим с дороги.

**О происхождении команды ЕСТЬ! (наверное, в качестве версии):**  http://www.vokrugsveta.ru/quiz/690/

Петр I для обучения нанял англичан, русские матросы должны были повторять все их действия. В частности, получив приказ, отвечать: Yes, sir! («Да, сэр»). Так под руководством английских моряков и двинулись русские корабли вниз по Дону. За каждым приказом на английском языке следовал ответ, который в русских устах звучал как **«есть».**

Comment: И где же запятая? В словаре ее нет.

Comment: Да, в словаре запятой нет, но в заданном предложении  она ставится.  Там возможны две формы с разным значением.:  Принята команда сняться с якоря. - Команда принята, снимаемся с якоря.

Comment: А как быть в таком случае? _"Зарядить осколочный!"— "Есть, осколочный!"_

Comment: Принята команда: зарядить осколочный. Принята команда: осколочный. Есть: осколочный. Так, получается?

Comment: Зарядить осколочный!"— "Есть (зарядить) осколочный!"  Постановку запятой можно проверить по наличию или отсутствию паузы в устной речи. В этом случае паузы нет.

Comment: Путаница получается. Выходит, что осколочный есть в наличии. Слово _есть_ становится формой глагола _быть_.

Comment: *Есть* - синоним *так точно*.  Но *есть* не принято отделять запятой. Военнослужащий должен был повторить приказание. "Осколочный!" — это приказание. Ответ: "Есть осколочный" (Так точно, осколочный)

Comment: У слова ЕСТЬ несколько значений,  которые следует различать, поэтому ответ на команду не может стать глаголом

Comment: "Зарядить осколочный!"— "Есть  осколочный!" А пропуск глагола допускался в ответе?